# How to parse a pipe or redirection operator in unix?

Tags: c, unix

I am currently working on a cat program. The problem I am having is that whenever I execute the unix command:

```
./catpr file1 file2 file3 | grep string
```

I don't know how to mark the end of the parsing by pointing out there exists a pipe operator.  I am currently developing this cat program in C by using system calls, so I use argv to keep track of the arguments; however, whenever I look at the content in the array that corresponds to '|', something really weird shows up.

Comment: "_whenever I look at the content in the array that corresponds to '|', something really weird shows up._" - Please show the code. Something like `if(strcmp(argv[4], "|") == 0)` would work.

Comment: The pipe is interpreted by the shell. You don’t have to deal with it.

Comment: You are likely reading past the end of the array. Check your `argc`.

Comment: You never read the pipe, you are piping the **output** (`stdout`) of `./catpr file1 file2 file3` to `stdin` of `grep string`, there will never be an `argv` related to the pipe itself.

Answer (score -1):

So what you basically need is you need to search a pattern in three files.

Since you have specified that you are using **system** calls to perform what you can do is give the string as input argument to program. Just do the following for compiling

> ./catpr file1 file2 file3 string

Just inside the program give the system call with grep. I am providing the complete program for you. I hope this is what you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int a,char *argv[])
{
    char com[256]="";
    strcat(com,"cat ");
    strcat(com,argv[1]);
    strcat(com," ");
    strcat(com,argv[2]);
    strcat(com," ");
    strcat(com,argv[3]);   
    strcat(com," | grep ");
    strcat(com,argv[4]);   //this is your search pattern
    system(com);
}
```

Comment: This may not be an answer if he hasn't mentioned that he is using **system** calls.This is an alternative way to do what he intends to do.